# List item background images outside div

Tags: css, list

I have an unordered list within a div. The list-item-images float outside the div, what can I do about this? Example on http://www.brainmove.be/wordpress/recente-cases/

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I fail to see the issue. Are the images not supposed to be inside the boxes next to the text?

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start by setting the margin:0; padding:0; on the ul; then set the list-style-position:inside;
you may want to float the ul so it doesn't span through the image as well.

Comment: hey Stefaan, glad it worked out. please select an answer, mine or Neil's as correct. Ive had it bashed into my head that this is a big deal round here ;)